# directory.listFiles() возвращает null в android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Уже не знаю что делать. такой каталог есть - это `/storage/emulated/0`. сделал разрешения в манифесте.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

В mainActivity запросил разрешение.

```
    val PERMS: Array<String> = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

    fun checkPermissions() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            requestPermissions(PERMS, 1)
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main))
        checkPermissions()

    }
```

Comment: Что делать? Смотреть на targetSdk, изучать теорию и писать код по-новому: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно добавить в манифест в application ещё вот такую строку.

```
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: Это костыль, который могут с очередной новой версией системы отключить.

Comment: Это костыль, но он работает :)